# Fluent nHibernate dynamic property name

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I want to make this mapping work:

```
    Map(x => x.First, "First_ID");
    Map(x => x.Second, "Second_ID")

    References(x => x.SomeProperty)
        .Access.AsCamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore)
        .Nullable()
        .NotFound.Ignore()
        .WithColumns("First_ID", "Second_ID")
        .LazyLoad();
```

It doesn't work when I want to insert the entity to the database. It says:
Invalid Index N for this SqlParameterCollection with Count=N error

I've found an answer for the question here:
http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2009/03/19/nhibernate-and-invalid-index-n-for-this-sqlparametercollection-with-count-n-error.aspx

But the answer says I need to remove below code, to make insert work

```
  Map(x => x.First, "First_ID");
  Map(x => x.Second, "Second_ID")
```

The problem is that I can't remove the mappings cause in that way my entity couldn't be fetched from the database. It than says that it cannot find First and Second columns in table. 
I understand why this happens but is there some way to solve the problem without removing the mappings? 
Just to change something in this code:

```
References(x => x.SomeProperty)
        .Access.AsCamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore)
        .Nullable()
        .NotFound.Ignore()
        .WithColumns("First_ID", "Second_ID")
        .LazyLoad();
```

For example not to use literals for column names, but some code that "knows" that in this mapping property First is mapped to "First_ID" without specifying explicitly the name of the column?

P.S. I've tried to use

```
References(x => x.SomeProperty)
        .Access.AsCamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore)
        .Nullable()
        .NotFound.Ignore()
        .WithColumns(x => x.First, x => x.Second)
        .LazyLoad();
```

It doesn't work.

The other solution for removed mappings is to change the query that gets the entity from db, but in this case i need to add extra join - it's stupid cause I have the column in my own table, why i need to make join and then add some restrictions when I don't exactly need this join.

Comment: The properties First and Second exist in your SomeProperty object right?  Why do you need to map these.  Can't you just access them like this: Entity.SomeProperty.First?  Maybe I'm not understanding you correctly.  Also what version of FNH are you using.  WithColumns is no longer in FNH to my knowledge.

Comment: You're right, we use old version of FNH. It's version is 0.1. I can use them! But in this case(i don't know why) query that gets the entity from db fails. It can't find the "First" and "Second" column... It should use "First_ID" and "Second_ID". Funny, for insert this code works, and for getting entity doesn't.

Comment: Maybe you should see why your query doesn't work when you don't have these mapped.  It looks like this way may be a dead end if you are stuck with an older version of FNH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify that the properties should not be updateable by doing:

```
Map(x => x.First, "First_ID").Not.Update();
Map(x => x.Second, "Second_ID").Not.Update();
```

Or if the only reason you want to have these properties is to use them in queries. You can 
either do

```
Map(x => x.First, "First_ID").Access.None();
Map(x => x.Second, "Second_ID").Access.None();
```

Or more simply remove those properties and use good old fashion hbm files to map your entities and specify `access="none"` for your properties. That way they will be available to you through Criteria and HQL, but won't actually need to exist in your entity.

Comment: I think we're using old version of the fluent nHibernate, cause I don't have .Not.Update() or .Access.None() methods. I have 0.1 version of Fluent...

Comment: I'm not familiar with the limitations of that version. Is there a specific reason why you can't upgrade to a newer version? If not I guess you'll need to play around to find the appropriate methods that would set `update="false"` or `access="none"` in the mapping. Or perhaps you can just use regular xml mapping files.

Comment: It's all about the project I'm working on. It is large and we use old version of the library and I can't use xml mappings.

Comment: You can have a mix of fluent mappings and xml mappings with FNH.  I'm not sure about your version but I would assume you can.